# How merge with appending two nested dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example I have two dicts:

```
schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'reseller_name': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
        'timestamp': {
            'type': 'integer',
        },
    },
    'required': ['reseller_name', 'timestamp'],
}
```

and

```
schema_add = {
    'properties': {
        'user_login': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
    },
    'required': ['user_login'],
}
```

How I can get next merged with appending result dict:

```
schema_result = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'reseller_name': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
        'timestamp': {
            'type': 'integer',
        },
        'user_login': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
    },
    'required': ['reseller_name', 'timestamp', 'user_login'],
}
```

Rules:

Same path is `properties` and `required` for `scheme` and `scheme_add` in example.

1. If both dict have dicts with same path, they merged with same rules.
2. If both dict have lists with same path, then add first list with second.
3. If both dict have simple values (or dict and non dict or list and non list) with same path, then first value overriding with second.
4. If only one dict have key with some path, than setting this key and value.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. The rules you have listed *is* your answer. Are you having trouble implementing that? If so, what precise problem are you having?

Comment: It looked difficult before I listed rules. Now with @Nicolas78 help I do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the problem likes, but the way you're writing it down is almost like a computer program, and the example is like a test case. Why don't you start from this?

```
def add_dict(d1, d2):
    newdict = {}
    for (key, value) in d1.iteritems():
        if key in d2: ...
            #apply rules, add to newdict, use 
        else:
            #simply add
    for (key, value) in d2.iteritems():
        if not key in d1:
            # simply add
    return newdict
```

This can probably be written more tightly, but might be easier like that to edit.

Edit.. after writing the last comment, couldn't help but write a nicer implementation

```
def merge_values(a,b):
    if a==None or b==None:
        return a or b
    # now handle cases where both have values
    if type(a)==dict:
        return add_dict(a, b)
    if type(a)==list:
        ...

def add_dict(d1,d2):
    return dict(
        [
            (key,
             merge_values(
                 d1.get(key,None),
                 d2.get(key,None)))
            for key
            in set(d1.keys()).union(d2.keys())
        ])
```

Answer (score 2):

My own solution with **@Nicolas78** help:

```
def merge(obj_1, obj_2):
    if type(obj_1) == dict and type(obj_2) == dict:
        result = {}
        for key, value in obj_1.iteritems():
            if key not in obj_2:
                result[key] = value
            else:
                result[key] = merge(value, obj_2[key])
        for key, value in obj_2.iteritems():
            if key not in obj_1:
                result[key] = value
        return result
    if type(obj_1) == list and type(obj_2) == list:
        return obj_1 + obj_2
    return obj_2
```

Comment: If you set `result = dict(obj_2)` then you can remove the entire second for loop.

Comment: `result = obj_2.copy()` more faster

Comment: Ah, I only noticed now you're the questioner.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to test types using `if type(obj_1) == dict` since this would exclude subclasses of dict.  It is usually preferable to use `if isinstance(obj1, dict)`.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding simple solution of this problem. Assuming that sample data will not change.

```
def merge_nested_dicts(schema,schema_add):
    new_schema = schema
    for k in schema:
        if k in schema_add.keys():
            if isinstance(schema_add[k],dict):
                new_schema[k].update(schema_add[k])
            if isinstance(schema_add[k],list):
                new_schema[k] = new_schema[k]+schema_add[k]
    return new_schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you know the keys exactly.

```
schema['properties'].update(schema_add['properties'])
schema['result'].append(schema_add['result'])
```

result is merged in schema.

If you do not know the keys exactly then one loop is required to find inner list and dictionaries.

```
for value in schema:
    if value is dict:
        if schema_add.has_key(value) and schema_add[value] is dict:
            schema[value].update(schema_add[value])
    elif value is list:
        if schema_add.has_key(value) and schema_add[value] is list:
            schema[value].append(schema_add[value])
```

result can be merged into different dict as well.